# What does Laravel EmailVerification controller's contruct method do?

Tags: laravel

In the `construct` method of the default `VerificationController.php` of Laravel, I see:

```
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
```

What do these three middlewares do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. auth middlware makes sure that user is logged in.
2. singned is related to URL signing, which means attching encrypted data as query param  more at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#signed-urls
3. throttle 6,1 means you can't make more than 6 request per minute.

Only means it is applied to only selected controller methods

Comment: So, if the user is not logged in, he cannot verify his email ?

Comment: They didn't mention anything about it in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification